# Multiple aggregate functions in the same query using LINQ expression

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there a LINQ expression equivalent to the following SQL query?

`SELECT MAX(col1) AS m1, MAX(col2) AS m2 FROM MyTable`

To clarify, I'm looking for a LINQ expression, which has the same semantics and dispatches one SQL query to the DB.

Comment: To the moderator: I don't think this is an 'exact duplicate' as the question appears to be can you use LINQ in a single line to perform the same functionality, semantically as SQL, in a single query. You've linked to an EF specific question.

Comment: In answer to the poster: I don't really think it's straight forward to get it done in a single line (depending on the object you're 'selecting' from), so maybe just var m1 = myTable.col1.Max(); var m2 = myTable.col2.Max();

Comment: Exactly, @peteski22. Thanks for the clarification. Is it possible to express the same semantics of the SQL query in a single LINQ to SQL expression.
A solution similar to the one linked the EF question still issues two SQL queries.

Comment: If you just mean in a general sense (rather than dealing with a SQL DB, using EF - in which case that linked answer) maybe post a question with an example object you want to query (knock up a class etc.). I think you'd end up having a convoluted bit of code though when 2 lines suffice to show the intent.